# python - ImportError - help configure environment to use with postgresql module

Tags: python, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Python newbie here. I'm trying to figure out how to connect to a postgresql database using python.I need help setting up this environment (Guest VM with Fedora 12). I have postgresql 9.3 and wanted to use Psycopg2 which I think comes with postgres?

I'm getting the following message:

```
$ python LearningPsycopg2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LearningPsycopg2.py", line 5, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

I have postgres installed and python installed. I'm not sure how python is installed, but this is what I have so far:

```
-bash-4.3$ which python
/bin/python
-bash-4.3$ python -V
Python 2.7.8
-bash-4.3$ cd /bin/
-bash-4.3$ ls -ltr python*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   301 Jun 18  2014 python3-mako-render
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   301 Aug 18  2014 python-coverage
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    15 Aug 18  2014 python2-coverage -> python-coverage
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 Nov  3  2014 python3 -> python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 11288 Nov  3  2014 python3.4m
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 11288 Nov  3  2014 python3.4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 Nov 10  2014 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     7 Nov 10  2014 python -> python2
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  7120 Nov 10  2014 python2.7
```

Here's my python script:

```
#!/bin/python2.7
#
# Small script to show PostgreSQL and Pyscopg together
#
import psycopg2

try:
   conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='foo_bar_99999' user='foo_bar' host='localhost' password='abc#123!'")

except:
   print "I am unable to connect to the database"

cur = conn.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("""SELECT * from foo_bar_99999.ups_date""")
except:
    print "I can't SELECT from ups_date"

rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print "   ", row[1][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually install pyscopg2, it doesn't come by default with either Python or PostgreSQL. There are [very detailed instructions here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html).

On a side note, it may be a good idea to change your shebang line to accommodate for different locations Python could be installed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

This should call the python2 instance the user has specified as "the default" for him.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the detailed link to the doc. I will check this out.

Comment: I was able to install that package. Now, I'm getting another python message: `cur = conn.cursor() NameError: name 'conn' is not defined`. Isn't `conn` already defined in the package? I'm simply trying to follow this tutorial for postgres here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial

Comment: `conn` is defined in the `try`-block and as Python doesn't have block scope (only function scope), it should be available after the `try-except`-block if it succeeded. However you can't be sure of that. You should move all of the code into the `try`-block. However, this is an unrelated question and to get support you should open another question and close this (as it is solved).